# Why favor object.__setattr__(self, name, value) only in new style classes?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, setattr, new-style-class

According to Python 2.7.12 documentation:

> If `__setattr__()` wants to assign to an instance attribute, it should
>   not simply execute `self.name = value` — this would cause a recursive
>   call to itself. Instead, it should insert the value in the dictionary
>   of instance attributes, e.g., `self.__dict__[name] = value`. **For
>   new-style classes, rather than accessing the instance dictionary, it
>   should call the base class method with the same name, for example,
>   `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`**.

However, the following code works as one would expect:

```
class Class(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        self.__dict__[name] = val;

c = Class()
c.val = 42
print c.val
```

I know `super(Class, obj).__setattr__(name, value)` can ensure the `__setattr__` methods of all base classes to be called, but classic class can also inherit from bases classes. So why is it only recommended for new style classes?

Or, on the other hand, why is doing so not recommended for classic classes?

Comment: *So why is it only recommended for new style classes?* Calling `__setattr__` instead of operating on the instance dictionary directly allows the superclass some "supervision" of what's going on.  Think of this approach as an advantage of new style classes.  It'd likely be recommended for all classes but old-style classes that don't inherit *don't have* a superclass with a callable `__setattr__` method.

Comment: @jedwards Yeah, because there is no `classobj.__setattr__` for classic classes, only `object.__setattr__` for new style classes.

Comment: You're exactly right.  My point was that I viewed the sentence you put in bold, not so much as discouragement from using the instance dict directly (as you showed, it works perfectly fine in many cases, and as Martijn showed, there are cases where it won't), but more of an *encouragement* to use `__setattr__`, which allows the superclass some* oversight and the use of newer features such as descriptors.  Sorry if I was unclear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New-style classes could be using *slots*, at which point there is no `__dict__` to assign to. New-style classes also support other *data descriptors*, objects defined on the class that handle attribute setting or deletion for certain names.

From the [documentation on slots](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> By default, instances of both old and new-style classes have a dictionary for attribute storage. This wastes space for objects having very few instance variables. The space consumption can become acute when creating large numbers of instances.
>
> The default can be overridden by defining `__slots__` in a new-style class definition. The `__slots__` declaration takes a sequence of instance variables and reserves just enough space in each instance to hold a value for each variable. Space is saved because `__dict__` is not created for each instance.

Access to slots is instead implemented by adding [data descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) on the class; an object with `__set__` and / or `__del__` methods for each such attribute.

Another example of data descriptors are [`property()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) that have a setter or deleter function attached. Setting a key with the same name as such a descriptor object in the `__dict__` would be ignored as data descriptors cause attribute lookup to bypass the `__dict__` altogether.

`object.__setattr__()` knows how to handle data descriptors, which is why you should just call that.

Comment: Maybe "Setting a key for such an object in the `__dict__` would be ignored" should be "Setting a key for an object whose class uses data descriptors in the `__dict__` would be ignored" to make it clearer?

Comment: @sunqingyao: the 'object' in question is the data descriptor on the class.